# How can I implement APNS in the same way WhatsApp does?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, whatsapp

I am currently working on an iOS app that allows users to make calls and send messages to eachother, effectively it is WhatsApp with a few extras.

When one of the users is offline, I send an APNS to the other user that brings up a short notification. The notification that is shown works well for messages but when it comes to an incoming call, it would be nice if it stuck around on screen and the phone vibrated for an extended period.

From what I have read, you cannot alter the vibration pattern of an APNS. WhatsApp, however, has managed to do it and I was wondering if anybody had an idea of how they achieve this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not 'how-to' website - instead the goal is to solve problems with code that you've written.  [help]

Comment: @KevinDTimm Sorry Kevin, new to StackOverflow and just wanted the best advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [VoIP Push Notifications (PushKit)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html). These are special push notifications intended to be used for VoIP call notifications.

Some source to get started:

- http://blog.biokoda.com/post/114315188985/ios-and-pushkit
- http://pierremarcairoldi.com/ios-8-voip-notifications/

Comment: P.S.- VoIP Push Notifications (PushKit) is available for `iOS8 and above`